# How to do -On Button click of a webview which is inside android app , a specific app screen opens?

Tags: android, android-webview, deep-linking

I have some webview in my android app. So on click of a button inside webview, need to open a specific app screen using deeplink. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create some custom JS interface and handle this click, how to [HERE](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#BindingJavaScript)

another aproach would be to use custom `WebViewClient` set for `WebView` with overriden [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)) method and inside of it apply your own logic for opening some other `Activity` or whatever, and then `return true`. if passed url should be loaded in `WebView` just `return false`